# Working with Multiple Radio Group values in Android

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have two radio groups, each contains two radio buttons. I would like to wait until a button from each group has been selected, and then display a Toast. (E.g. if radio button 1 from group 1 AND radio button 3 from group 2 aree selected, display Toast message. I am not getting any error messages with the following, but no Toast is displaying:

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/rb1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/rb2" />
    </RadioGroup>


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="228dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/rb3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/rb4" />
    </RadioGroup>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

JAVA CODE:

```
    package com.example.rgapp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }


        public void onClick(View view) {

            boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


            if (view.getId() == (R.id.rb1) & (view.getId() == (R.id.rb3)))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1 and 3 selected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: where you implements `OnClickListener` in your java code

Comment: First you should define your radio groups and radio buttons then use them by onClickListener().

Comment: @Android He/She has implemented `onClick` in all XML. check `RadioButton`

Comment: 1) don't set click listeners in XML, soon or later you will get a headache because of it. 2) `&` is not the operator you want here to check `AND`. 3) `view.getId()` can never be both `R.id.rb1` and `R.id.rb3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below xml and java

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onCustomClick"
            android:text="rb1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onCustomClick"
            android:text="rb2" />
    </RadioGroup>


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="228dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onCustomClick"
            android:text="rb3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onCustomClick"
            android:text="rb4" />
    </RadioGroup>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*MainActivity.java* :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RadioButton rb1, rb3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb1);
        rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb3);

        rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onCustomClick(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onCustomClick(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        if (rb1.isChecked() && rb3.isChecked())
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1 and 3 selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

It will display toast, if `radiobutton1` from group 1 AND `radiobutton3` from group 2 are selected.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code to achieve your functionality if both the radio group is selected then you will get result

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

        RadioGroup rg1,rg2;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            rg1 =(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg1);
            rg2 =(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg2);

            rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        }
        int radioId1 = 0,radioId2 = 0;
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {

            if (radioGroup == rg1){

                radioId1 = i;
            }
            if (radioGroup == rg2){
                radioId2 = i;
            }

            if (radioId1 != 0 && radioId2 != 0){
                RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioId1);
                RadioButton radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioId2);
                Toast.makeText(this,radioButton1.getText()+" and "+radioButton2.getText()+" is selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```